# Flags do ArrayIterator

Tags: php, spl

Não entendi o que realmente faz as flags 
`STD_PROP_LIST` e `ARRAY_AS_PROPS` quando configuradas

Procurei alguns exemplos, porém a explicação ficou meio confusa pra mim, sou iniciante em php

Comment: De fato, encontrei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469220/what-reason-of-using-arrayobjectstd-prop-list) no SOEN, mas acho que está muito vaga.

Comment: Aparentemente, foi reportado nesse [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45595) que a partir das novas versões do PHP essa flag não afeta o comportamento do objeto `ArrayObject`, mas apenas em versões mais antigas do PHP.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Explicação [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16619183/6510304), mas está em inglês. Teria que traduzir :/

Comment: Sobre a documentação do PHP: Não tente entender, apenas aceite :p